# Javascript - How to replace a simple string

Tags: javascript, jquery, str-replace

I have tried every variation to replace the string, "sub events" with "selected. I haven't touched "sub events" yet but have affected everything around it.

This hid everything after it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$("div[class$=registrationDetails] > ul > li").text(function(){
     var str = $(this).text("and the sub events").str.replace("sub events", "selected");
});
});
</script>
```

I tried the W3 School method, which I also found on another StackOverflow post, and it did nothing. This is the most basic form I tried with this method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var str1 = "and the sub events";
var str2 = str1.replace("sub events", "selected");
</script>
```

It seems so close yet won't just replace as it should. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `[class$=registrationDetails]` when looking for an element with a class. Use `div.registrationDetails`

Comment: Your problem is the use of jQuery is wrong. Is the text in the page already?

Comment: What result are you expecting after you have replaced the string?

Comment: Your guidance is appreciated! I switched to use the div.registrationDetails and that does target the correct section. I have another script on the page removing some dates just below the place where I want the outcome to say "selected" instead of "sub events". The page with no changes to it looks like this:

Comment: <div class="panel-body registrationDetails">
 will be registered for <strong> Hospitality Volunteer Oportunities</strong>
 <ul style="list-style: none;">
  <li>and the sub events 
  <ul>
   <li>6/30/2020 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM : Volunteer at North Campus</li>
   <li>6/30/2020 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM : Volunteer at South Campus</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>

Comment: I successfully "popped" the dates from the nested <li> using:

Comment: $("div[class$=registrationDetails]").find('li > ul > li').each(function() {
    $(this).text( $(this).text().split(':').pop() );
});

Comment: Now, I want to replace "sub events" with "selected" and I tried all of the answers below, which look slightly different than the scripts I have tried, but with same result - I lose the bullet point list below that of the options selected. Everything ends up in one line.

Comment: "and the selected Volunteer at North Campus Volunteer at South Campus" Instead of having the North and South lines as bullet points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the script to replace the text and maintain the html list formatting.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('div.registrationDetails > ul > li').html(function(i, htm){
    return htm.replace(/sub events/, 'selected');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

First revise how you're returning your value in the callback and `replace` as so. This is all assuming that the `<li />` has the text you're looking to replace.

```
$(function(){
  $("div[class$=registrationDetails] > ul > li").text(function() {
    return this.innerText.replace("sub events", "selected");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do what you want with a each loop. Used a if statement to look to see if the match is there

```js
$(function() {
  // select the class with a dot, not attribute selector
  $("div.registrationDetails > ul > li").each(
    function() {
      /// read text
      var text = $(this).text()
      // check if text is there
      if (text.includes('sub events')) {
        // if it is replace
        var str = text.replace('sub events', 'selected')
        //update the element
        $(this).text(str) 
      // another change
      } else if (text.includes('selected')) { 
        var str = text.replace('selected', 'sub events')
        $(this).text(str) 
      }
    }
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="registrationDetails">
  <ul>
    <li>foo bar sub events</li>
    <li>other selected</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There are other ways to do this, but this is a basic step in what you were trying to do.

A more complicated way to do it is with text and a reg exp with replace.

```js
// called by the replace method
// returns the opposite of what was matched
function replacerFnc (match) {
  return match==="sub events" ? "selected" : "sub events"
}

// What is called by jQuery's text method
function replacement(index, text) {
  // regular expression with groups to match either one of the strings
  var re = /(sub events|selected)/
  // use the reg exp and replace the string
  return text.replace(re, replacerFnc)
}

// basic jQuery code to select the lis and set the text
$(function() {
  $("div.registrationDetails > ul > li").text(replacement);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="registrationDetails">
  <ul>
    <li>foo bar sub events</li>
    <li>other selected</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The top suggestion you provided came very close to working. I have generated the same outcome with a similar script. The issue is that the list below "sub events" loses its formatting and the options selected end up on the same line with the replaced text "selected". I am hoping to preserve the bulleted list under the "selected" line. I can't grab "sub events" and preserve the formatting.

Comment: your solution worked to replace the text and straightened me out on selecting the class. I found the way to replace the text and maintain the html list formatting and wanted to note it for the next person.
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('div.registrationDetails > ul > li').html(function(i, htm){
        return htm.replace(/sub events/, 'selected');
    });
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

This thing worked for me.

var str1 = "and the sub events";

str1 = str1.replace("sub events", "selected")

console.log(str1)

Output -

[Running] node "..\test.js"
and the selected